# Any alternatives for xlwings and udf for macos?

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings, macos-monterey

my usecase:

i have an excel spreadsheet and a python function that uses pandas to take advantage of my spreadsheet. I would like to select some data (table/entire sheet to be precise) and would like to pass that data to a custom function i wrote in python and the I want the function to return a dataframe that i would want to show in the spreadsheet.

Apparently, i have followed through the documentation but found **On Mac, *all UDF* related functionality is not available.** on the [Xlwings doc page](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#xlwings-addin). Since this is for my work i cannot use another machine and apparently, the requirement cannot be achieved using the xlwings addin for macos MSExcel.

Are there any alternatives for achieving the same? Also, please correct me, if i got it anywhere wrong or any thing that i should do in making my requirement work in my environment?

Comment: Why don't you just use `pd.read_excel`/`pd.ExcelWriter` and/or something like `openpyxl`? Why do you need Excel for anything other than viewing?

Comment: Instead of a UDF, you could create a `RunPython` macro with the same inputs and outputs.  The only difference would be that a button might need to be clicked to update the data instead of automatically updating.